# How do I plot a histogram of response times from an ApacheBench output file using GNUPlot?

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, apachebench

I am running some benchmarking against a website I'm building and would like to produce graphs of the response times. Here's my ApacheBench usage:

```
> ab -n 100 -c 10 -g foo.tsv http://foo/
```

This gives me a TSV file with data like so:

```
starttime                   seconds         ctime    dtime  ttime   wait
Tue Dec 03 16:24:53 2013    1386087893      2        413    415     367
Tue Dec 03 16:24:49 2013    1386087889      1        468    469     452
Tue Dec 03 16:24:54 2013    1386087894      9        479    488     446
Tue Dec 03 16:24:49 2013    1386087889      1        497    498     437
Tue Dec 03 16:24:54 2013    1386087894      33       465    498     458
Tue Dec 03 16:24:53 2013    1386087893      1        507    508     506
Tue Dec 03 16:24:51 2013    1386087891      0        544    544     512
```

I'd like to convert this data to a histogram with quantity on the Y axis and response time (ttime) on the X axis.

My plot script is below but all I'm getting is an empty (zero byte) jpeg file.

```
clear
reset
set output "out.jpg"
# Select histogram data
set style data histogram

set style fill solid border

plot 'foo.tsv' using 5
exit
```

How can I generate this histogram?

---

Bonus question. I realise this data might lead to many data points with one or two hits, so how can I round the ttime to, say, the nearest 10ms to give me fewer data points with more hits each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1. If you want to output a `jpg` file, you must use `set terminal jpeg` first. But in any case I would suggest you to use the `pngcairo` terminal, if you need a bitmap image.
2. The `tsv` uses tabs as column separator. By default gnuplot uses any white space character as separator, in which case the fifth column is always `2013`. So use `set datafile separator '\t'`.
3. In order to have some binning, you must use `smooth frequency` with an appropriate binning function, which bins your x-values. As y-values I use `1`, so that `smooth frequency` just counts up.
4. Possibly you must skip the first line of your data file with `every ::1`.
5. In your case I would use `boxes` plotting style:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'foo.png'
set datafile separator '\t'
set style fill solid border
set boxwidth 8 absolute
set yrange [0:*]
bin(x) = 10*floor(x/10.0)
plot 'foo.tsv' using (bin($5)):(1) every ::1 smooth frequency with boxes title 'ttime'
```

Comment: It's actually pretty difficult to tell if the every ::1 is necessary. Are you sure that gnuplot isn't automatically ignorning the text on the first line of a .tsv file?

Comment: @netpoetica I know, that there are problems with the header line when plotting histograms, see e.g. [Redundant space at right side of Y axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676515/redundant-space-at-right-side-of-y-axis). I wasn't sure about the case when plotting with boxes. That's why I wrote 'possibly'. However it seems indeed that it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 5):

copy this into your .p file.

```
touch foo.p   
gedit foo.p
```

now paste this data into that file and save it,

```
 # output as png image
 set terminal png

 # save file to "benchmark.png"
 set output "benchmark.png"

 # graph a title
 set title "ab -n 100 -c 10 -g foo.tsv http://foo/"

 # nicer aspect ratio for image size
 set size 1,0.7

 # y-axis grid
 set grid y

 # x-axis label
 set xlabel "request"

 # y-axis label
 set ylabel "response time (ms)"

 # plot data from "foo.tsv" using column 9 with smooth sbezier lines
 plot "foo.tsv" using 9 smooth sbezier with lines title "server1:"
```

now generate the plot file of the foo.p by ::

```
    gnuplot foo.p
```

Answer (score 2):

I've summarized everything from this thread on this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#URL to test
URL_ATAQUE="http://foo.bar"
#Results file
FICH_RESULT="resultados.tsv"
#Plot
IMAGEN_RESULT="grafica.png"

echo -e "Executing bench on $URL_ATAQUE\nPlease, wait..."

#Sintaxis: 
#-n = Number of requests
#-c = simult. connections
#-g = output file
ab -n 5 -c 1 -g $FICH_RESULT $URL_ATAQUE

touch $FICH_RESULT

echo "set terminal png" > plot
echo "set output \"$IMAGEN_RESULT\"" >>plot
echo "set title \"$URL_ATAQUE\"" >>plot
echo "set size 1,0.7" >>plot
echo "set grid y" >> plot
echo "set xlabel \"Request\"" >> plot
echo "set ylabel \"Response time (ms)\"" >> plot
echo "plot \"$FICH_RESULT\" using 9 smooth sbezier with lines title \"server1:\"" >>plot

gnuplot plot

rm plot
rm $FICH_RESULT

gnome-open $IMAGEN_RESULT
#USE BELOW IF NOT IN GNOME
#xdg-open $IMAGEN_RESULT
```

Just chmod +x if necessary and run with ./fileName

Comment: I don't really know why this answer is downvoted, it gives me the solution what I've searched for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a more complete set of helper scripts for apachebench results plotting, including merging of multiple test results, you can check them out [here](https://github.com/juanluisbaptiste/apachebench-graphs).