# Redundant space at right side of Y axis

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to make plot with GNU Plot for some data of experiments, but I cannot figure how to remove the redundant padding/space between Y axis and the first sample (left side of the first sample):

[image: The output plot has a redundant spaces at the left side of the first sample]

Code:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,800 enhanced font 'WenQuanYiZenHei,12'
set title "All Elements"
set xlabel "Sample"
set ylabel "Element Amounts"

set ytics nomirror
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
plot data u 2:xticlabels(1) w histograms title "K",\
     data u 3:xticlabels(1) w histograms title "Ca",\
     data u 4:xticlabels(1) w histograms title "Mg",\
     data u 5:xticlabels(1) w histograms title "Fe",\
     data u 6:xticlabels(1) w histograms title "Mn",\
     data u 7:xticlabels(1) w histograms title "Zn"
```

Data:

```
| Sample |     K |    Ca |   Mg |     Fe |    Mn |   Zn |
|--------+-------+-------+------+--------+-------+------|
| -Ca 1U | 58800 |  4800 | 2700 |  222.5 |  28.0 | 30.0 |
| -Ca 2U | 59000 |  5475 | 3200 |  105.5 |  29.5 | 35.0 |
| -Mg 1U | 57600 | 12275 | 2900 |   92.0 |  45.5 | 37.0 |
| -Mg 2U | 57200 | 13850 | 3200 |  266.0 |  59.5 | 39.0 |
|--------+-------+-------+------+--------+-------+------|
| -Ca 1D | 19700 |  1100 | 3400 | 1708.0 |  79.0 | 48.5 |
| -Ca 2D | 20900 |  1025 | 3300 | 1812.0 | 102.5 | 54.5 |
| -Mg 1D | 23200 |  3175 | 3200 |  312.0 |  49.5 | 61.0 |
| -Mg 2D | 21800 |  4325 | 2300 | 2136.0 |  86.5 | 55.5 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the header line in the data. You can skip it with

```
plot data every ::1 u 2: ...
```

Or just remove it before feeding the data to gnuplot.